# Call more than 1 action in form

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm doing a few changes in a client API, which consists in some form validation and stuff.

I'm trying to set more than 1 submit handle to the form, since I have 2 buttons with different actions that takes the whole form as argument, but I can't achieve it reading the content about multiple handlers in the internet.

Here's what I have so far

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ValidarFormulario", "Cotacao", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm" }))
{
   ...
}
```

The "ValidarFormulario" is the main method that must be called by 'submit', IT WORKS, but I want a new button of 'save', that will do something else in a separated method

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" formaction="SalvarFormulario" value="SalvarFormulario" href='##'>Salvar</a>
```

I have both methods in my API,`ValidarFormulario` and `SalvarFormulario`, how can I post the same new form to both routes trough 2 different buttons?

Comment: why you didn't use SalvarFormulario action as your main action which calls ValidarFormulario for validating to whether submit or not!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up [writing a blog](https://medium.com/@bahreinihooman/submitting-a-form-to-different-action-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-c7a06e3c2766) about this question and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zBBkUA) is the link for the examples:

There are different ways to indicate the action method when submitting a form:

**1. Submit button inside the form (default behavior):**

This is the mos common scenario, we have one submit button inside the form. When we submit the form, it is postback to form’s submit action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Enroll", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {@class="form-control"}) 
   </div>

   // form is postback to /Home/Enroll
   <input type="submit" value="Enroll" class="btn"/>
}
```

**2. Submit button outside the form:**

If your submit button is outside the form, you can use the `form` attribute to indicate the form that should be used for postback:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Enroll", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myFrom" }))
{
   <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {@class="form-control"}) 
    </div>
}

// submit button is outside the form, it would postback to form's postback action: /Home/Enroll
<input type="submit" value="Enroll (outside)" form="myFrom" class="btn"/>
```

**3. Multiple submit buttons, posting back to different action methods:**
     If you have more than one submit buttons and you want each button to postback to a different action, then use `formaction` attribute on your button:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Enroll", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {@class="form-control"}) 
   </div>

   // your main submit button will post back to: /Home/Enroll (default behavior)
   <input type = "submit" value="Enroll" class="btn"/>
   // your Delete button will post back to: /Home/Delete
   <input type = "submit" value="Delete" formaction="@Url.Action("Delete")" formmethod="post" class="btn" />
}
```